# How to set verticalAlignment while using multlibinding in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, alignment

I try to set a style of the ListBoxItem. In the second TextBox (where I just bind PhoneNumber) the text is properly aligned. But in the second one (where I use TextBox StaticResource and multibinding inside) verticalAlignment doesn't work - it doesn't change text at all.

```
<Style x:Key="ItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>

                <Trigger Property="IsSelected"  Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <DockPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"
                                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                               DockPanel.Dock="Left"></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PhoneNumber}" 
                                               VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                               DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Right"></TextBlock>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Trigger>
```

Here is my TextBlockStyle:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Text">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                        <Binding Path="Name"/>
                        <Binding Path="LastName" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Instead of putting:

```
<Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
```

in TextBlockStyle I should put it in ItemStyle.